# sockect.gethostbyaddr in a for loop read from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to feed a text file list through socket.gethostbyaddr and I seem to be stuck on a data type issue.

when try to loop through the list I'm getting no output except an Exception error on my last test line

This is just a small script to resolve ip to name if one exists.  To test my opened file is just:

```
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
10.1.1.1
```

with my local hosts having an entry for the first two lines to a "test1"or "test2" name

just running socket.gethostbyaddr('1.1.1.1') returns "test1" as the host so I know that part is correct for testing

```
import subprocess
import socket
tstout = open('testout.txt','w+')
with open("testip.txt", "r") as ins:
    for l in ins:
        line = str(l)
    try:
        tstout.write (socket.gethostbyaddr(line))
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
tstout.close()
subprocess.Popen([r'c:\Windows\notepad.exe',r'c:\scripts\testout.txt'])
```

Was expecting the output file to have the resolve results written to it, any pointers where I messed this up is appreciated

Simplified to:

```
import socket
tstout = open('testout.txt','w+')
with open("testip.txt", "r") as ins:
    for l in ins:
        l = str(l)
#        print(l)
        tstout.write (socket.gethostbyaddr(l))
```

Comment: Your `for` loop iterates over all the lines of the file, reading each into `line` - *and does nothing else with them*.  After the loop, you *then* actually do something with `line`, but at that point it only holds the last line of the file.  You need to move those four lines into the loop (by indenting them one more level), so that they're repeated for each line.

Comment: in addition  to @jasonharper , you can remove the ```try``` and ```except``` , if you do worried about exceptions, enclosed them outside the for loop

Comment: I'm just not getting it (yes I am just starting with python..) simplifying down the script, I'm convinced this is a datatype conversion issue, running this in iPython the console tells me "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not tuple"

Comment: The socket.gethostbyaddr() just does not line the data type format the variable is feeding it.  Just a simple one line text file reduced down to 1.1.1.1 - thats it now, no multi-line

Comment: https://pythontic.com/modules/socket/gethostbyaddr - outputs a tuple and write function does not like it, wants string I guess the choice is write a formating function to just get the first section of the tuple ... or try the dnspython module.   got the output of a single test - ('test1', [], ['1.1.1.1']) - any comments appreciated. TY

Comment: Hummm,,, OK, got by the write a tuple issue by indexing - "tstout.write (l[0])" got a good output to the file, but as soon as I add a second IP to the input file it fails at the socket level [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed - so that might be the timing issue I've been reading about with this function ... read some more I guess